# Set checkboxes as checked using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have some checkboxes and their value is in database are 'Y' or 'N' as enum.for making updation i have to review all the checkboxes.how to view checkboxes as checked.
this is code for checkboxes

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="newItem.have_voter_id"  value="have_voter_id" /><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_voter_id'); ?>
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="checkbox"   ng-model="newItem.have_passport" value="passport" /> <?php echo $this->lang->line('label_passport'); ?>
 </label>
```

and this is the function for view and updation

```
 $scope.edit = function(id,family_id) {

    $scope.action = 'update';
    FamilyMem.get({id:id,family_id:family_id}, function (response) { // success            
        $scope.newItem = response.data; // store result to variable            
          $("#myModal").modal('show');
        }, function (error) { // ajax loading error
            Data.errorMsg(); // display error notification
            //$scope.edit = false;
        });
  };
```

and edit button

```
  <a href="" class="btn btn-magenta btn-sm" ng-click="edit(family_member.id,family_member.family_id)">
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `ng-checked` for check-boxes,

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="newItem.have_voter_id"  value="have_voter_id" ng-checked="newItem.have_voter_id=='Y'"/><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_voter_id'); ?>
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="checkbox"   ng-model="newItem.have_passport" value="passport" ng-checked="newItem.have_passport=='Y'"/> <?php echo $this->lang->line('label_passport'); ?>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The model `newItem.have_voter_id` and `newItem.have_passport` is set to `true` or `false` according to your action on the checkbox. If the checkbox of 'voter_id' is checked then the value of the model `newItem.have_voter_id` will be updated to `true` and if unchecked the value will be updated to `false`. And the same goes for the other checkbox.

Comment: for saving the values from checkbox i have done that.but while i want to update it shows again as unchecked even it is true in database

Comment: Could you please make a fiddle? It's difficult to find out the problem with these less code.

Answer (score 0):

The below link helped me a lot.

You need to initialize model and then if model value match with value it will be get selected.

Comment: The below link helped me a lot.

You need to initialize model and then if model value match with value it will be get selected.http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/ZQDts/3/